# java equivalent to .NET MVC4 + Entity Framework (I mean options like Grails, Spring MVC..etc.. not sure)

Tags: c#, java, asp.net-mvc

This is a simple and very specific question: If you have been doing a project with .NET MVC4 and Entity Framework with lots of jQuery/Json using, of couse, Visual Studio 2012, and you are asked to produce a "Java-based" / "open" platform, what architecture / tools would you choose?.

I would prefer not to "automatically migrate". I prefer to seriously re-code in a platform with similar features from point of view of 'coding by conventions' strong types..,DB generation from model, preferable code first..etc, integrated automating testing..etc

I am not trying here to go into any debate like '.net' vs 'java' or things like that. This is just a concrete question about tooling and architecture. The reason of my asking is that I am a "java guy' by birth but ended up in .NET for the last few years and I lost track of cool new things.

Without admitting 'loving' Microsoft, I have to confess I really like Visual Studio 2012, MVC4 and Entity Framework 5. But, lot of companies / people prefer Java for valid reasons I do not want to argue about.

I have been looking at Grails at some point but did not have time to compare all options seriously so I do not know.

Comment: asp mvc by microsoft is an open and free software under apache licence. See at least [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)

Comment: After some google, I ended up liking this article a lot http://erniepaschall.blogspot.ca/2012/04/scrumtime-grails-20-vs-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at http://playframework.org/? As a c# programmer I found it real easy to find my way.

It also implements the MVC pattern, and has some nice database connection stuff. I've used it with Google BigTable which is a different approach because there's no table schema. And of course it has unittesting and selenium testing integrated. #awesome :)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement to try, I did heard about it when I ended up trying Grails. So, I would aded to my short list.